# approaching models from the other side of a foreign key

Tags: django, django-orm

Working with [Django docs'](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/) sample `Blog` and `Entry` models, how would one get a queryset of all `Blog` objects that have `name = "a"` and that are not associated with any instance of the `Entry` model?

In raw (My)SQL terms, what is the Django ORM equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_table bt
WHERE bt.name='a' AND bt.id NOT IN (SELECT et.blog_id FROM entry_table et)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a list of `Blog` instances that have `name = "a"` and do not have any associated entries. You can do this by:

```
Blog.objects.filter(name = "a", entry = None)
#                   ^^^^        ^^^^^
#           <Match name>        <Should have no associated Entry instances>
```